How to Visualize ATAC-seq Peaks with Transcription Factor Binding Sites Using IGV
I have a question regarding visualising ATACseq peaks and transcription factor binding sites. I uploaded bigwig files to IGV and I am wondering if there is a way to label transcription factor binding sites on top of those tracks based on publically available data. If that is possible can anyone let me know how to do it? I am doing my analysis in R. Thanks a lot for help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
